# Подсчитать кол-во напитков по ID в datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, count

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

DataGrid загружается из SQLite, как в DataGrid  подсчитать  Quantity по DrinkId что бы в дальнейшем вывести кол-во напитков за определенный период ?

Comment: `.Where(x=>x.DrinkId == 1).Sum(x=>x.Quantity);`

Comment: Как именно их в гриде перебрать ?? dataGrid.Items.Where(x=>x.DrinkId == 1).Sum(x=>x.Quantity);

Comment: Если у вас WPF приложение, то использование DataGrid, как источник данных - бред. Вы с базы когда берете данные, получаете наверно `List<SomeClass>`, вот с ним и работайте. А для отображения в UI используйте привязки.

Comment: Спасибо, да действительно бред) сейчас почитаю про привязки